# How to put 'viper-change-state-to-emacs function on some hook

Tags: hooks, shell, major-mode

I am using viper-mode, which is `vi` emulator and can be switched to the original emacs mode with `viper-change-state-to-emacs`, when I edit program files.
But, sometimes I want to create some special interactive shell process buffers on emacs mode instead of the viper-mode (default).

First I have tried to change the default `viper-mode` on the newly created buffer to the original emacs mode  by `viper-change-state-to-emacs`.
So, I put following codes on `.emacs`, but they do not work for me.

```lisp
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook 'viper-change-state-to-emacs t) 
(add-hook 'py-shell-mode-hook 'viper-change-state-to-emacs t) 
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'viper-change-state-to-emacs t)
```

Probably I need to run those functions after the buffer creation processes have completed.
How can I hook functions at the last step of the buffer creation process?